# Using a RecyclerView inside of an adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

This might be a bit confusing, but hang in there and leave comments for clarification. I am using a RecyclerView within an adapter. This is because I want multiple rows in a ListView that can scroll horizontally. The number of rows is perfectly fine, but the number of items in each row is wrong. The first row displays the correct number of lines, but then the rows after that display multiple items in each row when I only want one. Row 1 displays 1 item (this is what I want), row 2 displays 2 items, row 3 displays 3 items etc. This is my fragment file that calls the first adapter:

```
public class featured_fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public  ArrayList<featured_post> featured_post_list = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public featured_fragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_activity, container, false);
        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.featured_list);
        featuredAdapter adapter = new featuredAdapter(getContext(),featured_post_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Row 1
        featured_post post = new featured_post();
        adapter.add(post);

        //Row 2
        featured_post post1 = new featured_post();
        adapter.add(post1);

        //Row 3
        featured_post post2 = new featured_post();
        adapter.add(post2);

        return view;

    }
}
```

My first adapter that calls the recycler adapater:

```
public class featuredAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<featured_post>{

private List<featured_post> featured_postList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private recycler_adapter adapter;
private Context context;



public featuredAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<featured_post> users){

    super(context,0,users);
    this.context=context;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    featured_post post_item = getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.featured_fragment_activity, parent, false);


    recyclerView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.featured_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

    adapter = new recycler_adapter(context,featured_postList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    featured_post post = new featured_post(Integer.toString(position));

    featured_postList.add(post);
    }
  return convertView
  }
}
```

Then, the final adapter named `recycler_adapter` (Please excuse this adapter, I was very confused when creating it):

```
public class recycler_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recycler_adapter.MyViewHolder> {
private List<featured_post> featuredList;
private Context context;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView text;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {

        super(view);
        this.text = view.findViewById(R.id.my_text);

    }
}

public recycler_adapter(Context context,List<featured_post> featuredList) {
    this.featuredList = featuredList;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_activity,null);
    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,int position) {

    featured_post featured_post = featuredList.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(featured_post.string);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return featuredList.size();
}
```

Any help as to why it is adding multiple items would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I fixed this issue by clearing the list at the beginning of the `getView` method inside of the `featuredAdapter`. However, I am getting an error saying:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 2(offset:2).state:4
```

Any ideas why this is happening all the sudden?

Comment: Seems something wrong when you initialize new recycler_adapter and pass featured_postList as an argument. After that you add another postList and it is logical that for next time when getView will called, the featured_postList will have one more element than previous list item

Comment: Here´s a  nested adapter that scroll horizonal [nested-recycler-view](https://github.com/msahakyan/nested-recycler-view). I used this Adapter myself and it´s useful

Comment: @Vigen I wish that I could debug the recyclerVIew better with breakpoints and see where it is going wrong but it acts so random. Never know how many times a method will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve my issues. First, to make sure that it doesn't put the same element more than once, I added a statement to clear the list inside of the getView method in the featuredAdapater:

```
featured_postList.clear();
```

Then, I got an IndexOutOfBoundsException because the clear statement was in the beginning of the method. Instead, I solved that by putting the statement inside of the `if(convertView == null)` statement. This solved my issues and now it works as intended.